# How To Use Mesibo on My WordPress Website

Tags: wordpress, plugins, mesibo

I'm new here and not a programmer. However, I have a wordpress website which I love to install mesibo on, how can I install Mesibo on wordpress website for chat, voice and video conferencing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an API to use it on WordPress. Here is the documentation:

https://mesibo.com/documentation/tutorials/get-started/